# C# problema com MAIN e origem

Tags: c#

Eu estava fazendo um programa no visual studio usando a liguagem C# até que surgiu esse erro e não sei como resolver:
[image: AJUDA POR FAVOR]

e o código era este 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão para resolver isto?

Comment: Poste o código ao invés da imagem

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, está tudo correto. Pode ser configuração do projeto que está fora do padrão.

Comment: Como você criou o projeto? Selecionou o template do Console Application?

Comment: provavelmente foi o projeto que deu erro,porém não sei como faze-lo corretamento

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que notei a sua classe não está dentro de um namespace.

O correto seria:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MinhaClasse
    {
        static void main(string[] args){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: uma excelente observação, mas isso ainda não é suficiente para reproduzir o problema e afirmar a solução

Comment: o main até ficou resolvido porém não o de origem

Comment: Seu projeto é um ConsoleApplication?